# npm is getting closed immediately - need to use npm for cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm

I am working on a Cordova project and have installed npm for the same. but it is not working. It is getting closed immediately after opening it.

I was unable to read the error also so I capture the screen with the use of a screen recorder.

and below is the error...

[image]

Comment: what error? that's just the help output for the node package manager... I wonder are you talking about node.js? to run in the command line just run `node` to start interactive mode

Comment: @Andrei I want to run npm... but it is closing itself

Comment: You are definitely running npm, and it's closing itself is correct, because you didn't pass in the parameters and commands for what you wanted to do with npm. Also I don't think you're supposed to directly run the npm executable. You just need to pass information to npm.